# Angular 2 min lngth validator doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a formGroup like this

```
this.profileForm = this._fb.group({
    'first_name': ['', Validators.required],
    'last_name': ['', Validators.required],
    'phone': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9)])],
    'emailGroup' : this._fb.group({
      'email': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirm_email': ['', Validators.required],
    },{ validator: EqualValidator }),
    'passwordGroup' : this._fb.group({
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
      'confirm_password': ['', Validators.required],
    },{ validator: EqualValidator })
  })
```

Everything works fine expect phone, it seems like angular ignores minLength validator. Just type one character and input is valid. What can be wrong with that code?

Comment: How do you run the validation?

Comment: `phone: AbstractControl; 
this.phone = this.profileForm.controls['phone']
if(this.phone.valid){}`

Comment: @Agr why are you using declarations for each form field and doing reassignment of the form control? You can check validity via `this.profileForm.valid` or specific form control valid property.

Comment: Cause it's shorter to write in template, for example
`profileForm.controls.emailGroup.controls.email.valid vs email.valid`

Is it bad practice?